# Having trouble in c# fraction calculator

Tags: c#

I have an assignment due tomorrow that has to add and subtract fractions with whole numbers, and I'm getting a bit confused with all these numbers, and the Math isn't helping either.

It's performing the Math correctly, but it keeps putting a 1 for the whole variable when it should be 0 and I can't figure out for the life of me why.

Here's my Fraction.cs:

```
class Fraction
{
    int num, den, whole, newnum;

    public Fraction(int numerator, int denominator, int whole = 0)
    {

        this.num = numerator;
        this.den = denominator;
        this.whole = whole;
    }

    public Fraction Add(Fraction other)
    {
        int temp1 = num, temp2 = den;
        if (Math.Abs(this.whole) > 0)
        {
            newnum = temp2 * whole;
            newnum = +temp1;
            temp1 = newnum;
        }
        if (Math.Abs(other.whole) > 0)
        {
            other.newnum = other.den * other.whole;
            other.newnum = +other.num;
            other.num = other.newnum;
        }
        temp1 = temp1 * other.den + temp2 * other.num;
        temp2 = temp2 * other.den;
        if (temp1 == temp2 || temp1 > temp2)
        {
            whole = temp1 / temp2;
            temp1 = temp1 % temp2;
        }

        Fraction newFrac = new Fraction(temp1, temp2, whole);
        return newFrac;
    }
}
```

and inside my Program.cs here's my test:

```
Fraction fra1 = new Fraction(1, 2);
Fraction fra2 = new Fraction(3, 4, 1);
Fraction fra3 = fra1.Add(fra2);
Console.WriteLine("Fraction 1: " + fra1);
Console.WriteLine("Fraction 2: " + fra2);
Console.WriteLine("{0} + {1} = {2}", fra1, fra2, fra3);
```

and here's what I'm currently getting as a result:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advanced.
Austen

Comment: "It's performing the Math correctly" - except, it's not. 1/2 + 7/4 != 5/4, which is what your program spits out.

Comment: it almost looks like you're attempting subtraction

Comment: `1 3/4 - 1 1/2` does equal `2/8`

Comment: @SamIam Except, the first number is supposed to be 1/2. It is only inadvertently changed at the end of `Add()`, as per p.s.w.g's answer.

Comment: Think of some better names for your variables and consider delegating the repeated parts to a common method, the reason you stumbled is your code is far too close to incomprehensible.

Comment: Once you've fixed the bug, you could perhaps post the working version on the code review stack exchange site. You can get a lot of advice on how to write something like this more cleanly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is this line:

```
whole = temp1 / temp2
```

It seems you're accidently modifying the `whole` value of the current instance. That's what's causing `fra1` to 'magically' change from `1/2` to `1 1/2`. Use a temporary variable instead and that should fix the problem, but I'd also recommend making similar adjustments to avoid accidentally modifying the fields of `other` too as well removing the `newnum` field which is apparently there just as a temporary placeholder for calculations.

If you intend to make this class immutable, I'd also recommend making each of the fields [`readonly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx) to avoid these errors.